# Unable to fetch the firebase data in the node js api

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch some data from firebase datastore. When tring to push the same data to a node js based rest api, its not showing any data but no error as well. And while checking though postman, its showing 200 OK.

- **blog.js** `[Showing data as expected]`

```
import { db } from "../configAuth/firebase-admin-config.js";

async function getBlogs() {
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection("myBlogs").get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
  });
}

export default getBlogs = getBlogs();
```

But when importing the `getBlogs` to the `index.js`, its not showing any data via http://localhost:5000/api/blogs which is my end point.

- **index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import getBlogs from "./blogs/blog.js";

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("API is running...");                //working
});

app.get("/api/blogs", (req, res) => {
  getBlogs.then((blogs) => {                  // not working
    res.json(blogs);
  });
});

const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server sarted on PORT ${PORT}`));
```

If I am trying to loading data from a data.json file, `index.js` is able to load that data correcty and I am able to see the data in http://localhost:5000/api/blogs as well. And able to push the data to the frontend which us using react native.

Getting the following out put which is coming from `blog.js`:

```
[nodemon] starting `node src/index.js`
Server sarted on PORT 5000
YzBuR9QG4xaVzcXU3JyP  =>  {
  blogId: '9087612312390871231',
  createdAt: Timestamp { _seconds: 1659399096, _nanoseconds: 632000000 },
  content: 'content of testing firebase 01',
  createdBy: 'Udayendu Kar',
  published: true,
  updatedAt: 0,
  tags: [ 'firebase', 'development' ],
  title: 'testing firebase'
}
yUsB7V79Vhs9uCQPlhg0  =>  {
  blogId: '9087612312390871232',
  published: 'false',
  createdBy: 'Udayendu Kar',
  tags: [ 'nodejs', 'react' ],
  updatedAt: '0',
  createdAt: Timestamp { _seconds: 1659780527, _nanoseconds: 628000000 },
  title: 'testing node 02',
  content: 'content of testing node 02'
}
```

Comment: Can you try commenting working section `app.get("/", functionCall)` and try calling your main API

Comment: @PradeepYenkuwale already tried that but no impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getBlogs`  is an `async` function, your export is a `Promise` and not the value you want to send to the caller.

To send the actual value to the response, you can use `await` or `then`:

```
app.get("/api/blogs", (req, res) => {
  getBlogs.then((blogs) => {
    res.json(blogs);
  })
});
```

---

Also: your `getBlogs` function is not returning any value. Did you mean for it to be:

```
async function getBlogs() {
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection("myBlogs").get();
  return querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data());
}
```

Comment: Thank for the response Frank but still not working. And no error as well.

Comment: "still not working" is really hard to help with. This was definitely one problem with your code, but there might be other problems too. I recommend stepping through the code in a debugger, checking the value of each variable on each line. When doing this, what is the first line/variable that isn't what you expect it to be?

Comment: getBlogs is the first variable its getting in `index.js` and after enabling the debug I can see `Promise { undefined }` even after using `then`.

Comment: That seems unexpected. Can you edit your question to show the code where you applied my answer at the bottom?

Comment: Its in `index.js` file. I have just updated it.

Comment: Your `getBlogs` function is not returning anything. Is that intentional?

Comment: No. infact I want to sructure it in a better way, so that I can call it inside all other codes as needed. My plan is to keep all blog related activities inside blog.js like get, put, edit & delete function. So started with get only.

Comment: OK, so did you see the update I made to my answer, also showing you how to return the blog data from the documents?

Comment: Thanks Frank for all your help. Finally its able to return the data. Just change the code from `querySnapshot.doc.map` to `querySnapshot.docs.map`.

Comment: Oops, good catch on that type in the update to my answer. I updated it again.

Answer (score 0):

Update your route as follows

```
app.get("/api/blogs", getBlogs);
```

and return the result from the calling function.

```
async function getBlogs() {
  const querySnapshot = await db.collection("myBlogs").get();
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data())
  });
  return querySnapshot;
}
```